# Redis message queue with Spring

Tags: java, spring, redis

I have implemented a [following](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/) Redis Publish - Subscribe messaging with Spring. I noticed that this configuration doesn't support message queuing in case there are no subscribers. How can I achieve this to ensure that all messages which were sent to Redis are received at some point in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a database store ALL messages and only resend messages to the user if they don't already have the message id cached on the frontend. There are multiple other solutions, but that is what I would do.

When you send the message to the server to be published you should also store it in a SQL database and when a new user subscribes, give them any set of already published data they missed from the past that is stored in your database.